# some questions about static library in gcc

Tags: c, gcc, static-libraries

I have make two libraries *libsa.a* and *libsb.a*.
The function *funca* in *libsa.a* and *funcb* in *libsb.a* which calls *funca*.

In the main function, I only call *funcb*. The compiler display that "... undefined reference to `*funca*'". The compiler command like "gcc main.c -o main -lsa -lsb".

The problem is resolved when I add a *funca* in the main function.

What can I do?

Sorry for my poor English!

Comment: possible duplicate of [linker woes - undefined reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143530/linker-woes-undefined-reference)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the order: `gcc main.c -o main -lsb -lsa`

Comment: gcc link order is from left to right and it is auto discard the library if it is not be referenced.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add each source file, you try to compile. If there are 2 sourcefiles which you want to achieve to your lib, you have to do  `gcc sourcefile1.c sourcefile2.c -o XYZ [...]`